# I want to Convert Mysql Blob to String and then String back to Blob

Tags: java, mysql, blob

I have stored jar file into a Blob (Mysql table). I could do it with following codes:

```
blob = rset.getBlob(1);
byte[] bdata = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
String s = new String(bdata);
sb.append(s);
```

Upto here I could do it successfully. But the issue is when I am taking back to Blob then size (length) is increasing to almost double, I dont know why. File is prepared but could not be extracted (unknown format error)

```
while ((response = reader.readLine()) != null  ) {
       if(!response.equals("")) {
reader.lines().forEach(line -> sb.append(line));
       blob = new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(sb.toString().getBytes());
       `enter code here`String filename = "blob.zip";
                                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                                if (blob != null) {
                                    InputStream in = blob.getBinaryStream();
                                    int len = in.available();
                                    int data = 0;
                                    System.out.println("downloading to " + filename);
                                    byte[] bytin = new byte[1024];
                                    while ((data = in.read(bytin)) != -1) {
                                        fos.write(bytin, 0, data);
                                    }
                                    fos.flush();
                                }
```

Comment: "I want to Convert Mysql Blob to String and then String back to Blob" Why? Strings are character sequences stored as bytes in a special encoding. This is different from pure byte sequences or binary data, what BLOBs are. And that's your problem here. So why converting BLOBs to String and vice versa?

Comment: As mentioned above I stored files (jars/exes/etc.) in the blob (mysql). I want to download using Java Servlets. I could successfully fetch blob data into String Builder (codes given above). Now using java class from desktop I will be accessing Servlet (URL connect) and fetch the SB and extract the file.

Comment: But using a `String` as container is wrong here. A `BLOB` contains binary data, not characters in a special encoding as a `String` does. Please see https://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/java-servlet-to-download-file-from-database.